# If $\vec a\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is non-zero, then $\left \{ \vec e_1\times\vec a,\vec e_2\times\vec a,\vec e_3\times\vec a \right \}$ is linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

Proof: write
$$\;\vec a=(\alpha,\,\beta,\,\gamma)=\alpha e_1+\beta e_2+\gamma e_3$$
then we have
$$\alpha \vec e_1\times\vec a+\beta \vec e_2\times\vec a+\gamma \vec e_3\times\vec a=(\alpha \vec e_1+\beta \vec e_2+\gamma \vec e_3)\times\vec a=\vec a\times \vec a=\vec 0$$
$$as\;(\alpha,\,\beta,\,\gamma)=\vec a\neq\vec 0$$
the set
$$\;\{\vec e_1\times \vec a,\, \vec e_2\times \vec a ,\, \vec e_3\times \vec a\}$$
is linearly dependent.
now we know the proposition is true, but if you look at the contraposition: if the set
$$\{\vec e_1\times \vec a,\, \vec e_2\times \vec a ,\, \vec e_3\times \vec a\}$$ is linearly independent then$$ \vec a=\vec 0$$
which means $\vec e_i \times\vec a=\vec 0,$ the set is linearly dependent, contradiction!
What's wrong with that?

Comment: I notice that the set is linearly independent essentially, even if $\vec a=\vec 0$. I feel that's a hint

Comment: There is no contradiction because the set $\{\vec{e}_1\times\vec{a},\vec{e}_2\times\vec{a},\vec{e}_3\times\vec{a}\}$ is always linearly dependent. The contrapositive is true the same way as the statement *if the Moon is made of cheese, then I am the emperor of China* is also true.

Comment: For second case, if $\{\vec e_1\times \vec a,\, \vec e_2\times \vec a ,\, \vec e_3\times \vec a\}$ is linearly independent then $\vec a =2 \vec e_1+3 \vec e_2$ is also true as the hypothesis is false.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen oh, that's right. the conclusion of any fallacy is true. thank for your remind

Answer (score 1):

All three cross-products are in the subspace  $\rm {span}\{a\}^\perp $, which is two-dimensional.